# Xamarin Monodroid auto update data on Android App

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is there a way or an example to use a service or something to auto update any changes made from an app to show on other devices using the same app?
We have a native/local application we use in-house for Android tablets for taking and editing data. More or less a check-in app. 
We were needing to:

1. If a users on one tablet makes a data change in their application, to automatically change the status/data on the other tablets running the same application without having to manually refresh or restart the application.
2. If a user makes a change to the data and saves it, could we cause a push notification to the other tablets to indicating a change to the data has been made.

Answer (score 1):

if you are working "online" or at least on a network, you could use a REST request to send your changes or a notification to a server (depending on what you need).  Then the notification to other devices can be handled through libraries like [Signal-R](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) or [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp)